# What is the difference between "Using and not using API key" while fetching records from Youtube API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am using the following url for fetching search results from youtube

**Url:**

> https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=lumia&key=********************&v=2&alt=json

I can understand that the above is Version 2.

But we also can fetch results without using this **API developer key.**

So what makes the difference?
Which is preferable?

Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main difference would be on quotas. If you don't use an API key, you would be bound to lower per IP quotas. Whereas if you use API key, since you are a known developer to request that feed, you'll have higher quota availabilities. So using API key is highly suggested.